# Format input as number with locale in Angular 6

Tags: locale, number-formatting, angular6

I am trying to format a number in a text input in the locale of the user. I tried to use `DecimalPipe` and a custom self-made pipe and both work at first. The problem is, as soon as the number is formated into a string, the pipe doesn't work anymore since it is supposed to be applied on a number.

So for example when I type `1234.23`, it displays `1 234,23` but the DecimalPipe doesn't work on `1 234,23` and I get the NaN error.

I didn't find anything that allows me to turn back the formatted text into a number again to reapply my pipe. For instance `Number("1 234,23")` doesn't work and returns NaN...

It is easy to get rid of the thousand separator space, but sometimes it is a comma and sometimes the comma is the decimal separator, so I need the locale to define how the string is formatted into a number.

Comment: I have not used in the past but maybe have a look at https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize as it should offer methods to reverse `toLocaleString` on numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I have created custom input component for this purpose and it is working fine in many system without any issue.

I have used ngx-translate for handling Internationalization in my system. Here is my implementation.

HTML

```
<input #input type="text" appOnlyNumbers (input)="onChange($event)" (keyup.enter)="enterKeyEvent($event.target.value)" class="form-control text-right w-100"
  [disabled]="disabled" (blur)="onBlur($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="value" />
```

Ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, forwardRef, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export const AMOUNT_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => AmountInputComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-amount-input',
  templateUrl: './amount-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./amount-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [AMOUNT_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})

export class AmountInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  @ViewChild('input')
  input: ElementRef;
  locale: string;
  value: any;
  @Input() disabled = false;
  @Input() hideClose = true;


  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() valueBlur = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() enterKey = new EventEmitter<string>();

  changeCallback = (data: any) => { };
  touchCallback = () => { };

  constructor(
    private translateService: TranslateService
  ) {
      // these should be 'en-US', 'nd-NO','de-DE' etc, should setup on ngx-translate settings
      this.locale = this.translateService.currentLang;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // **Language selecton and subscription - amountconverter uses this **
    this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(res => {
      this.locale = res.lang;
      this.input.nativeElement.value = this.format(this.value);
    });

  }

  onChange(event) {
    this.value = event.target.value;
    this.changeCallback(event.target.value);
    this.valueChange.emit(event.target.value);
  }

  writeValue(amount: any) {
    this.value = amount;
    this.input.nativeElement.value = this.format(amount);
    this.changeCallback(this.input.nativeElement.value);
    this.valueChange.emit(this.input.nativeElement.value);
    this.value = this.input.nativeElement.value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.changeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.touchCallback = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    this.disabled = disabled;
  }

  format(value: number | string) {
    let amount = value ? value.toString() : '0';
    amount = amount.replace(/\s/g, '');
    amount = amount.replace(/,/g, '');
    amount = amount.replace(/\./g, '');
    return (Number(amount) / 100).toLocaleString(this.locale, { minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
  }

  onBlur(value) {
    this.writeValue(value);
    this.valueBlur.emit(value);
  }

  enterKeyEvent(value) {
    this.enterKey.emit(value);
    this.input.nativeElement.value = this.format(value);

  }
}
```

To learn about number conversion refer following link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Following directive will not allow to add unwanted characters to the input. Used in input element of custom component

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appOnlyNumbers]'
})
export class OnlyNumbersDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    const e = <KeyboardEvent>event;

    if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 188, 190].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+A
      (e.keyCode === 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+C
      (e.keyCode === 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+X
      (e.keyCode === 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
      // Allow: home, end, left, right
      (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
      // let it happen, don't do anything
      return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<app-us-amount-input [(ngModel)]="Amount" (valueChange)="itemAmountChange()"></app-us-amount-input>
```

This can use inside reactive forms too.

```
<app-us-amount-input formControlName="Amount" (valueChange)="itemAmountChange()"></app-us-amount-input>
```

Sometimes following function will need to get value of input from component.

```
format(value: number | string) {
    let amount = value ? value.toString() : '0';
    amount = amount.replace(/\s/g, '');
    amount = amount.replace(/,/g, '');
    amount = amount.replace(/\./g, '');

    return (Number(amount) / 100);
  }
```

Hope this will help to someone.