# Formating Number / Currency in Angular 6 Directive

Tags: angular, format, currency, angular-directive

I created a Currency Directive which I will **use in every input element** which needs currency format.

So I have 2 Host Listeners one is OnFocus, the second is Blur

And it works perfectly. But I need to format the value of input when I set the value of input by binding

So when I open a modal I get unformatted value... NgOnInit doesn't work because it raises too much early

Here is my directive code.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, OnInit, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, OnChanges, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { CurrencyPipe, getCurrencySymbol } from '@angular/common';

import { NgControl, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

import { CustomCurrencyPipe } from '../pipes/custom-currency.pipe';

import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';



@Directive({

  selector: '[appCurencyFormat]',

  providers: [CustomCurrencyPipe]

})



export class CurrencyFormatDirective implements OnInit{

  //@Input('appNumberFormat') params: any;

  @Input() decimalNumber: number = 2;

  @Input() symbol: string = "symbol";

  //@Input() OnlyNumber: boolean;

  local: string;

  decimal: string;

  currency: string;

  element: any;



  @ViewChild(ModalDirective) childModal: ModalDirective;



  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private ngControl: NgControl, private currencyPipe: CustomCurrencyPipe, private _renderer: Renderer2) {


    this.element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;    

  }



  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {

    let e = <KeyboardEvent>event;

    //190 in array for .

      if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||

        // Allow: Ctrl+A

        (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||

        // Allow: Ctrl+C

        (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||

        // Allow: Ctrl+V

        (e.keyCode === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||

        // Allow: Ctrl+X

        (e.keyCode === 88 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||

        // Allow: home, end, left, right

        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {

        // let it happen, don't do anything

        return;

      }

      // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress

      if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {

        e.preventDefault();

      }    

  }  



  @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target.value'])

  onFocus(value: any) {

    this.ctrl.setValue(this.currencyPipe.convertToNumber(value));    

  }



  @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])

  onBlur(value: any) {

    this.ctrl.setValue(this.currencyPipe.transform(value, this.decimalNumber, this.symbol));

  }



  get ctrl() {    

    return this.ngControl.control;

  }

}
```

My solution is something with a set interval in ngOnInit...

```
ngOnInit() {
        let m = window.setInterval(() => {
        console.log("Upao sam");
        console.log(this.ctrl.value);
        if (this.ctrl.value) {
          console.log(this.ctrl.value);
          if (seted) {
            window.clearInterval(m);
          } else {
            seted = true;
            this.ctrl.setValue(this.currencyPipe.transform(this.ctrl.value, this.decimalNumber, this.symbol));
          }
        }
      }, 500);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea which HostListener I can use for it, to try to avoid using `window.setInterval()`. Or if anyone has any idea how can I resolve this problem?

**UPDATE**

`ngOnChanges()` isn't raised every time, so the selected duplicate question can't resolve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when an @Input() value changes in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571812/how-to-detect-when-an-input-value-changes-in-angular)

Comment: @jonrsharpe just possible... ngOnChanges doesn't raise every time

Comment: What is the challenge in using already available [currency-pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)

Comment: You can't use it in an input. First time you will enter for example 500, and pipe will return $500, next time you need to remove $ if you want to use pipe because pipe expect number not string

Comment: you can add default of 0 or nothing

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz/codesandbox demo of the issue?

Comment: I can try @MunimMunna

Comment: I get the error - Error in src/main.ts Out of stack space in Stackblitz for Angular Project. Do you maybe know how i can resolve it

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hlkm6y here it is but I'm not sure does it work i can't try on stackblitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the whole value accessor thing. Thats what I use for all my inputs. You can write something like this

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ks-input',
  template: `<input [(ngModel)]="value" />`,
  styleUrls: ['./whatever.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input('value') _value = '';
  onChange: any = () => {
  };
  onTouched: any = () => {
  };

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

  set value(val) {
    this._value = val;
    this.onChange(val);
    this.onTouched();
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

When you pass a variable to this component it will first pass through the writeValue function where you can do any initial formatting. you can also do what ever in the set value function which is called everytime the value/input ngModel variable changes.

Comment: Hmm, nice solution it can be. I'll definitely try it if I don't find a better solution.

Comment: @GlacialMan Yes, all of my form inputs are much more complex than the very simple example I showed with things like curency format, phone number format, ect. and I use that and it works wonders. With angular ive found thats the only way to have full control over your form controls. I think that was actually designed for your specific use case.

Comment: I'll give you a bounty because I tried all other solutions. Your solution must work but it's much more complex.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51474527/format-input-as-number-with-locale-in-angular-6

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem as you. I was able to solve it using NgControl hook to access the form control from the directive.

I added NgControl to the directive constructor:

```
constructor(
  private el: ElementRef, 
  private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe,
  @Self() private ngControl: NgControl) { }
```

This way, I was able to subscribe to the form control value changes observable. The observable triggers with both user and code changes, so to avoid formatting while the user is typing I validate that the control is pristine:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.ngControl.valueChanges
    .subscribe(value => {
      if (this.ngControl.pristine) {
        this.el.nativeElement.value = 
          this.decimalPipe.transform(value, `1.2-2`);
      }
    });
```

I hope it can be useful for someone else. I got the idea from this article https://netbasal.com/attribute-directives-angular-forms-b40503643089

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do to resolve this issue :

```
<input [ngModel]="item | customCurrencyPipe:'USD':'symbol':'2.2'" name="inputField" type="text" 
(ngModelChange)="item = $event||0.00" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}"/>
```

1) Split the binding into a one-way binding and an event binding.

2) With Event-binding "ngModelChange" restore value with the input provided.

3) Update Value on 'blur', so any text which is not a number cannot be served // optional based on requirement

4) **customCurrencyPipe** : This will have the default features of currency pipe, but will not escalate if a number is not provided instead will return the default value or won't allow other than numbers // based on requirement

With above steps, you will be able to achieve desired results with less hack and a promising solution.

Comment: Which event I can use for updateOn if I want to format numbers on keyPressed. I tried with keydown but it doesn't work. For some reason, I don't get $ only formatted numbers and only one-time debugger shows me that it's in my function transform of customCurrencyPipe. Another time I don't know where it goes.

Comment: you can use :
[ngModelOptions]="{ debounce:200,updateOn: 'change' }"

Comment: How I can move the vertical line... I can enter 1-2 numbers but all others going in the decimal part of number

Comment: This you have to address in your custom pipe, wherein you are passing '2.2' as second param. So, basic logic would be to get the number and filter it with your pipe to prepend it with the symbol. Now, the debounce time helps you to wait till user stops typing

Comment: hmm, I can use your solution but I want to format numbers on focus and on blur. On focus, I would like to use directive, on blur I would like to use a pipe. For example $123,123.00 - on focus will be 123123.00, when user change number on blur it will get $ and , separator for thousands. Is it possible?

Comment: Ideally the separator should corresponds to the region, for that you need to set [locale](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#setting-up-the-locale-of-your-app) , however if you want separator for thousands only, you can write your regex in your pipe itself and feed it to the output

Comment: yeah i have locale, but how it can be used in input?

Answer (score 1):

### The solution is format the value of input inside **`ngDoCheck()`** instead of `ngOnChanges()`.

`ngDoCheck()` is a guranteed life cycle hook that will run every time Angular trigger change detection.

[A small working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5uh3b2) showing that `ngDoCheck()` hook of the directive will always be triggered when there is change.

---

For understanding why **`ngOnChanges()`** does not raise all the time and why use **`ngDoCheck()`** instead:

Whenever a binding **`Input`** property from a directive changes, it trigger Angular change detection. And how Angular detect if that **`Input`** is changed ? It compare the [Simple Change](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChanges) object represent that **`Input`**'s old and new values, if there is differences between those, then Angular trigger **`ngOnChanges()`** life cycle hook.

So there is case that you did entered something but the value compared doesnt change( for example you change an **`Input`** by mutate and **`Object`** 's property, so actually the old and new value of the [Simple Change](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChanges) is the same because Angular is comparing the reference, not the value), in this case it does not raise the **`ngOnChange()`** hook.

---

But **`ngDoChek()`** is something different. I will use this informations [from a very good article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article-36ce63a3f3e5) regarding `ngDoCheck()`:

Suppose we have the following components/directive tree:

```
Component A
    Component B
        Component C
```

So when Angular runs change detection the order of operations is the following:

```
Checking A component:
  - update B input bindings
  - call NgDoCheck on the B component
  - update DOM interpolations for component A
 
 Checking B component:
    - update C input bindings
    - call NgDoCheck on the C component
    - update DOM interpolations for component B
 
   Checking C component:
      - update DOM interpolations for component C
```

As you seeing it, whenever there is change detection run, `ngDoCheck()` is always be called. Beside that, It also be called when the component/directive is intialized (reset the [my blitzstack example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5uh3b2) to see that). So:

**Format the value of input inside `ngDoCheck()` will solve your problem**

Comment: Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'model: undefined'. Current value: 'model: null'.

Comment: and it shows me an error every time when I enter the number by number...